# How to get child_id where all values of level_num is 250

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CHILD_NAME  LEVEL_NUM
    A          4
    A          5
    A          250
-----------------------
    B          5
    B          250
    B          250
------------------------
    C          250
    C          250
    C          250
```

i want C as the answer.how to get child_id whose all values of level_num is 250?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: why "C" is your answer?

Comment: C is the child_id whose All level_num values are 250

using microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 2):

You can use grouping with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT CHILD_NAME  
FROM mytable
GROUP BY CHILD_NAME  
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN LEVEL_NUM <> 250 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

The above query works provided that `LEVEL_NUM` is a `NOT NULL` column.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Corrected for `SQL Server` (Thanks to `a_horse_with_no_name`) for pointing it.

You have to use `except`. 
The first query will give you `A`,`B`,`C` and second will give you `A`,`B`. `except` will give you only `C`

```
select CHILD_NAME from table
except
select CHILD_NAME from table where LEVEL_NUM <> 250
```

Comment: Now that we know it's SQL Server you need to use `except` instead of `minus` (`minus` is Oracle's non-standard keyword for `except`) And the `distinct` isn't actually necessary the `except` (or `minus`) operator will automatically do that anyway

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Thanks for pointing it. I thought `minus` is `ansi` standard.
Also I couldn't get the fiddle for sql server working so let me know if this looks ok. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer
but it's not working. it is giving me those child_ids also whose some of the level_num values are other than 250.
i want the child_id whose all level_num values are 250


it is also giving me A and B.bcoz onf of the values of A and B are 250

Comment: try using `distinct` before `child_name` and try again. I couldn't test the query.

Comment: @vidhi_shah This query works fine. As Utasv said the first query will return you all the CHILD_NAME and the second query return all that CHILD_NAME which have atleast one row with LEVEL_NUM not equal to 250. In your case 1st query result will be (A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C) and 2nd query result will be (A,A,B). Using except you will get only C. In case u want only the distinct result form both 1st and 2nd query add distinct keyword in front of CHILD_NAME

Comment: Both answers will work but I would prefer @Giorgos Betsos answer since using 2 queries might slow down the performance.

Comment: see did the same thing.still not working


 1) select child_id from child_lkp 
 except 
 select child_id from child_lkp
 where level_num= any(select level_num from levels_lkp where levelnum!=250)

2) select child_id from child_lkp 
 except 
 select child_id from child_lkp
 where level_num <> 250

Comment: edited

see did the same thing.still not working 1) select child_id from child_lkp except select child_id from child_lkp where level_num= any(select level_num from child_lkp where levelnum!=250) 2) select child_id from child_lkp except select child_id from child_lkp where level_num <> 250